# How do `cal` options work?

Tags: cal

`cal` doesn't work with any options.  `cal -M` returns

```
Usage: cal [general options] [-jy] [[month] year]
       cal [general options] [-j] [-m month] [year]
       ncal -C [general options] [-jy] [[month] year]
       ncal -C [general options] [-j] [-m month] [year]
       ncal [general options] [-bhJjpwySM] [-H yyyy-mm-dd] [-s country_code] [[month] year]
       ncal [general options] [-bhJeoSM] [year]
General options: [-31] [-A months] [-B months] [-d yyyy-mm]
```

as does most/all other options I try to enter.  Same issue if I try `ncal -CM`.

`Cal` is such a simple utility that I'm surprised there would be any issue with it.  It just came installed on my 19.10 version of kubuntu.  `apt` doesn't even know about the existence of `cal`.  Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: As you can see from the usage message, `-M` isn't a valid option for `cal` - only for `ncal`. Can you confirm that `ncal -M` gives the same message? What is the output of `type -a cal`?

Comment: ```
cal is /usr/bin/cal
cal is /usr/bin/cal
```

Comment: `ncal -C` works.  But trying to add `-M` results in the same usage options being returned.

Comment: The `-m` option needs an argument (a month number or name) - did you give it one?

Comment: sorry, typo, `-M` was what I used, not lowercase `m`.  And I just discovered that `-b` is what I want, not `-C`.

Comment: Your comment @steeldriver about the usage message got me to read it more clearly, at first I wasn't understanding what it was saying.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The man page doesn't explain clearly what options can be used with `ncal` and what options can be used with `cal`.  It just illustrates them.  The SYNOPSIS of the man page and the usage message returned from entering an invalid option illustrate the valid combinations of options that exist and each command, `cal` and `ncal` -- these do not show `-C` being used in combination with `-M` because that combination is invalid and simply does not work.

To get the `cal` program to print Monday as the first day of the week, the command is `ncal -bM`.

Comment: `ncal` on macos 10.10 has no `-bM`; `ncal -s DE` does print weeks starting on Monday, vertical. See also [calendar.py](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html).